# Solving Second Order Non-Linear Differential Equations Using Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

How do I find the series solution to the following non-linear second order differential equation up to and including the $x^4$ term and plot the solution curve using Mathematica?

$y''= x + y^2$ (with given initial conditions: $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried inputting the following code to solve and plot the solution: a = DSolve[{y''[x] == x + (y[x])^2, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, y[x], x];
Plot[y[x] /. a, {x, -2, 2}],  but it did not compute. I have no clue about how to find the series solution either.

Answer (score 4):

The series solution is just $\frac{x^3}{6}$ (for these initial conditions)

```
findSeriesSolution[t_,nTerms_]:=Module[
  {pt=0,u,ode,s0,s1,ic,eq,sol,roots},
  ic={u[0]->0,u'[0]->0};
  ode=u''[t]-t-u[t]^2;
  s0=Series[ode,{t,pt,nTerms}];
  s0=s0/.ic;
  roots=Solve@LogicalExpand[s0==0];
  s1=Series[u[t],{t,pt,nTerms+2}];
  sol=Normal[s1]/.ic/.roots[[1]]
]
```

And

```
seriesSol=findSeriesSolution[x,5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[x^3/6,{x,0,2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to `NDSolve`

```
ClearAll[u,x]
sol=NDSolve[{u''[x]==x+u[x]^2 ,u[0]==0,u'[0]==0},u,{x,0,2}];
Plot[Evaluate[u[x]/.sol],{x,0,2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Verify also using Maple

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want general series solution for any initial conditions, then replace the line

```
ic = {u[0] ->0, u'[0] -> 0};
```

with

```
ic = {u[0] -> C[1], u'[0] -> C[2]};
```

In the above function., And now

```
seriesSol=findSeriesSolution[x,5]
```

$$
\frac{\left(20 c_2 c_1^3+6 c_1^2+5 c_2^3\right) x^7}{1260}+\frac{1}{360} \left(5 c_1^4+10 c_2^2 c_1+4 c_2\right) x^6+\frac{1}{60} \left(5 c_2
   c_1^2+c_1\right) x^5+\frac{1}{12} \left(c_1^3+c_2^2\right) x^4+\frac{1}{6} \left(2 c_1 c_2+1\right) x^3+\frac{1}{2} c_1^2 x^2+c_2 x+c_1
$$

You can see that for `C[1]=0` and `C[2]=0` the above gives $\frac{x^3}{6}$ since all other terms are zero.

Comment: Ohh ok, thank you so much!